# Extraer valor de la columna E de un .txt si ciertos caracteres del nombre del archivo coinciden con ciertos caracteres de la columna A del .txt

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un archivo 'eventlist.txt' que en la columna A tiene la fecha y en la columna E tiene la magnitud. Ese archivo está en un directorio que tiene archivos de sismogramas cuyos nombres son las fechas del evento.
Os pongo la estructura del archivo 'eventlist.txt'.

```
          A                             B          C         D         E
2010-09-21T08:32:45.320Z              34.987     52.754     12.8      6.1
2010-09-25T10:38:12.234Z              35.765     60.431     136.7     6.9
```

Los nombres de los archivos siguen la siguiente estructura:

```
2010_09_21_08_32_45.XXX.sac
2010_09_25_10_38_12.XXX.sac
2011_06_20_12_55_26.XXX.sac
```

El caso es que me gustaría extraer el valor de la columna E si coincide la fecha del .txt con la fecha del nombre del archivo que en este caso es AÑO_MES_DÍA_HORA_MINUTO_SEGUNDO quedando algo así:

```
[6.1]
[6.9]
[]
```

Es decir, los dos primeros archivos que sí coinciden con la lista del txt extrae los valores y el otro evento que no está en la lista no saca nada.

Hasta el momento lo único que he conseguido es hacer listas de cada línea del .txt con el siguiente script, pero todavía no tengo mucho recorrido en la programación.

```
with open('eventlist.txt', 'r') as f:
    lineas = [linea.split() for linea in f]

for linea in lineas:
    print(linea)
```

Os doy las gracias de antemano si podéis ayudarme. Estoy en primeros meses de python y estoy muy verde.

Comment: ¿Podría agregar el código fuente de lo que ha conseguido hacer hasta el momento?

Comment: Hola. He añadido lo que he conseguido hasta el momento (que no es mucho). Mi idea era empezar así, es decir, creando listas para seleccionar partes del string y ver si concuerda con el archivo, pero.....no se mucho todavía de python.